# How to make clickable links from objectdatareader vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox, datareader

This code works fine, the listbox shows the posts. But how do I get the posts on the front side show up as **clickable** links. Maybe not in the Listbox, perhaps in a panel or similar object?

```
If objDR.HasRows = True Then
   Do While objDR.Read()
      ListBox.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(objDR.GetString(1)
    Loop
End If
```

Comment: What you means by clickable links? You mean that the items in your ListBox will open in a WebBrowser when clicked?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show it as true links then you can't use the ListBox control. You could use a DataGridView and add a DataGridViewLinkColumn to it.

If you really want to use a ListBox control you could execute the link on the Click event.

Comment: Ok, i try to be more specific. I don´t wont to use griview or similar. More like panel or literal object. When for example, Animals, shows in my listbox (or panel) i want to be able to click on it as an weblink and animalid will come with the click. More like <a href="cats.aspx?Animalid=">Cats</a>...

Comment: Let´s say i use this code:  ListBox.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(objDR.GetString(1) & Convert.ToString(objDR.GetString(2) & vbTab & objDR.GetInt32(0)))) How can i in an easy way make these posts in my listbox clickable to different urls?

Comment: Here is my solution. One of the simplest ways maybe?  
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <table><tr>
  
   <td>   <a href="About.aspx?userid=<%# Container.DataItem("ID")%>"><%# Container.DataItem("ENamn")%></a>
 
   </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

Comment: and code behind       ' Me.Repeater1.DataSource = Cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            Me.Repeater1.DataBind()'